# Integration problem 174,Ch.10 - Calculus by N. Piskunov

Tags: calculus

I am trying to solve the problems in the section titled - *Integration of irrational functions* from the book Differential Calculus, N. Piskunov. My answer doesn't match that given in the text.

Could someone help me point, where I have made a mistake.

> Evaluate the integral
>
> $$I=\int{\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}\frac{dx}{x^{2}}}$$

**Solution.**
The given function is an irrational function $f(x) = \left(\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}\right)^\frac{1}{2}$.

We substitute,

$\displaystyle{\frac{1-x}{1+x}=t^{2}}$

We have:

$\displaystyle{x=\frac{1-t^{2}}{1+t^2}\\\frac{1}{x^2}=\left(\frac{1+t^2}{1-t^2}\right)^2}$

$\begin{align}
dx&=\frac{(1+t^2)(-2t)-(1-t^2)(2t)}{(1+t^2)^2}dt\\
&=\frac{(-2t)(1+t^2+1-t^2)}{(1+t^2)^2}dt\\
&=\frac{(-4t)}{(1+t^2)^2}dt
\end{align}$

We have:

$\begin{align}
I&=\int{\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}\frac{dx}{x^{2}}}\\
&=\int{t\cdot{\frac{-4t}{(1+t^2)^2}\cdot{\frac{(1+t^2)^2}{(1-t^2)^2}}}dt}\\
&=4\int{\frac{1-t^2-1}{(1-t^2)^2}dt}\\
&=4\int{\frac{dt}{(1-t^2)}}-4\int{\frac{dt}{(1-t^2)^2}}\\
&=4(I_{1}-I_{2})
\end{align}$

**The first integral $I_{1}$:**

$\begin{align}
I_{1}&=\int{\frac{dt}{(1-t^2)}}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{1+t}{1-t}\right)+c_{1}\\
\end{align}$

**The second integral $I_{2}$:**

Let us write

$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{(1-t)^2(1+t)^2}&=\frac{A}{1-t}+\frac{B}{(1-t)^2}+\frac{C}{1+t}+\frac{D}{(1+t)^2}\\
1&=A(1-t)(1+t)^2+B(1+t)^2+C(1-t)^2(1+t)+D(1-t)^2
\end{align}$

When $t=1$, $4B=1$. $\implies{B=1/4}$.

When $t=-1$, $4D=1$. $\implies{D=1/4}$.

Also,

$1=(-A+C)t^3+(-A+B-C+D)t^2+(A+2B-C-2D)t+(A+B+C+D)$

$-A+C=0. \implies{A=C}$

$A+B+c+D=1. \implies{A=C=1/4}$

$\begin{align}
I_{2}&=\frac{1}{4}\int{\frac{dt}{1-t}}+\frac{1}{4}\int{\frac{dt}{(1-t)^2}}+\frac{1}{4}\int{\frac{dt}{(1+t)}}+\frac{1}{4}\int{\frac{dt}{(1+t)^2}}\\
&=\frac{1}{4}\ln\left(\frac{1+t}{1-t}\right)+\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{1-t}-\frac{1}{1+t}+c_{2}\\
&=\frac{1}{4}\ln\left(\frac{1+t}{1-t}\right)+\frac{1}{4}\frac{2t}{1-t^2}+c_{2}
\end{align}$

**Resulting integral $I$:**

$\begin{align}
I&=4(I_{1}-I_{2})\\
&=4\left[\frac{1}{4}\ln\left(\frac{1+t}{1-t}\right)-\frac{1}{4}\frac{2t}{1-t^2}+c\right]\\
&=\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x}}\right)-\frac{2{\sqrt\frac{1+x}{1-x}}}{\frac{2x}{1+x}}+c
\end{align}$

Comment: you can differentiate your result to see if its right

Answer (score 2):

$$I=\int{\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}\frac{dx}{x^{2}}}=\int{\sqrt{1-x^2}\over x^3+x^2}dx$$

$$\color {teal} {x=sin(u) => dx=cos(u)du}$$

$$\sqrt{1-x^2}=\sqrt{1-\sin^2u}=\cos u $$

$$\int {\cos^2u\over \sin^3 u+\sin^2u}du$$

$$\color {blue} {t=\tan({u\over 2}) => dt={1\over2}\sec^2({u\over2})du}$$
$$\sin u={2t\over t^2+1}\,\,\,\,\, ,\,\,\,\,\, \cos u={1-t^2\over t^2+1}\,\,\,\,\, ,\,\,\,\,\,du={2dt\over t^2+1}$$

$$\int {({1-t^2\over t^2+1})^2\over ({2t\over t^2+1})^3+({2t\over t^2+1})^2}{2dt\over t^2+1}=\int{(1-t^2)^2\over 4t^3+(t^2+1)2t^2}dt=\int{(-(t^2-1))^2\over 4t^3+2t^4+2t^2}dt=\int{(t^2-1)^2\over 2t^2(2t+t^2+1)}dt=\int{(t^2-1)^2\over 2t^2(t+1)^2}dt =\int{(t-1)^2(t+1)^2\over 2t^2(t+1)^2}dt$$$$=\int {(t-1)^2\over 2t^2}dt={1\over2}\int{(t-1)^2\over t^2}dt$$

$$\color {olive} {w=t-1 => dw=dt}$$

$${1\over2}\int{(t-1)^2\over t^2}dt={1\over2}\int({w\over w+1})^2dw={1\over2}\int({-2\over w+1 }+{1\over(w+1)^2}+1)dw$$$$={1\over2}(w - {1\over(w + 1)} - 2 \log(w + 1) + C)={1\over2}(t-{ 1\over t} - 2 \log(t) )+ C$$

$$\color {blue} {t=\tan({u\over 2})}$$

$${1\over2}(t-{ 1\over t} - 2 \log(t) )+ C={1\over2}(\tan({u\over 2})-{ 1\over \tan({u\over 2})} - 2 \log(\tan({u\over 2})) )+ C$$

$$\color{teal} {x=sin(u) => u=\arcsin x}$$

$${1\over2}(\tan({u\over 2})-{ 1\over \tan({u\over 2})} - 2 \log(\tan({u\over 2})) )+ C$$$$={1\over2}(\tan({\arcsin x\over 2})-{ 1\over \tan({\arcsin x\over 2})} - 2 \log(\tan({\arcsin x\over 2})) )+ C$$

$$\bbox[yellow,5px] {\tan({\arcsin x\over 2})= {x\over(\sqrt{1 - x} \sqrt{x + 1} + 1)}}
 \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\small{.(1)}$$

$${1\over2}(({x\over(\sqrt{1 - x} \sqrt{x + 1} + 1)}
)-{ (\sqrt{1 - x} \sqrt{x + 1} + 1)\over x}
 - 2 \log({x\over(\sqrt{1 - x} \sqrt{x + 1} + 1)}
))+ C={1\over2}({-2 \sqrt{1 - x^2}\over x}
 - 2 \log({x\over(\sqrt{1 - x} \sqrt{x + 1} + 1)}
))+ C=({- \sqrt{1 - x^2}\over x}
 -  \log({x\over(\sqrt{1 - x} \sqrt{x + 1} + 1)}
))+ C
$$$$={- \sqrt{1 - x^2}\over x}
 +\log(\sqrt{1 - x^2}+ 1 )- \log{x} 
+ C=({- \sqrt{1 - x^2}\over x}
 +\log{\sqrt{1 - x^2}+ 1  \over {x}} 
)+C $$

$$\bbox[yellow,5px,border:2px solid red]{=\ln\begin{vmatrix}{\sqrt{1-x}+\sqrt{1+x}\over\sqrt{1-x}-\sqrt {1+x}}\end{vmatrix}-{ \sqrt{1 - x^2}\over x}+C
 }$$

---

<sup>(1)</sup>

$\small{\tan {x\over 2}= {\sin x \over1+\cos x} }\,\,\,\,,\,\,\,\, \small{\cos  x=\sqrt{1-\sin^2x}}$
$\small{\tan{\arcsin x\over 2}= {\sin \arcsin x \over1+\cos \arcsin x}={ x \over1+\cos \arcsin x}={ x \over1+\sqrt{1-[\sin\arcsin x]^2}}={ x \over1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}={ x \over1+\sqrt{1-x}\sqrt{1+x}} } $